# Java - How to sort vector of objects with different attributes

Tags: java, sorting, vector

I have a vector of objects.

```
class companyInfo {
    String name;
    int stat1;
    int stat2;
    double stat3;
    double stat4;
    double stat5;
}
```

I know how to sort a vector by implementing a Comparator using one of the attributes but I need to be able to sort dynamically. eg

```
public function() {
    for(int i = 0; i < number of different stats; i++) {
      //sort by stat(i);
      //do some analysis
    }
}
```

So that I can sort the vector by a specified stat, do some analysis on the vector. Then sort by another stat, do the same analysis etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement different comparators, one for each class field and use them in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right in you function, implement Comparator on the spot using different sorting criteria, using [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

```
public function() {
    for(int i = 0; i < number of different stats; i++) {
      //sort by stat(i); Implement Comparator
      //do some analysis
      //sort by stat(i); Implement Comparator again 
      //do more analysis
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Bean Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/). It allows you to sort on any property in the Object by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write this in a compact way, you could define yourself a sortBy method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <A, B> void sortBy(List<A> list, Function<A, B> f) {
  Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> ((Comparable<B>)f.apply(e1)).compareTo(f.apply(e2)));
}

public void function(List<CompanyInfo> list) {
  sortBy(list, c -> c.stat1);
  //do some analysis
  sortBy(list, c -> c.stat2);
  //do some analysis
  //etc.
}
```

But you still have the problem that you can't simply loop over the stats. To do that you'd have to put all the stats into a list or hash map. That list could e.g. be of type `List<Number>`. In the worst case you have to use a `HashMap<String, Object>` and cast the values where necessary.